# Returning zero when the key is not exist in unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I have the following container:

```
std::unordered_map<uint8_t,int> um;
```

`um` is assumed to have keys between 0 and 255 but not all of them. So, in certain point of time I want to ask it to give me the value of the key 13 for example. If it was there, I want its value (which is guaranteed to be not 0). If not, I want it to return 0.

What is the best way (performance point of view) to implement this?

What I tried till now: use find and return 0 if it was not found or the value if it was found.

P.S. Changing to `std::vector<int>` that contains 256 items is not an option. I can not afford the space to storing 256 values always.

---

**EDIT:**

My problem is histogram computing problem keys (colors 0-255) values(frequent, int is enough). I will not be satisfied if I just know that some key is exist or not. I also need the value (the frequent).

**Additional information:**

- I will never erase any item.
- I will add items sometimes (at most 256 items) and usually less than 10.
- I will query on key so so many times.
- Usually querying and inserting come with no specific order.

Comment: well on average `find` is constant time so I doubt you will find anything faster.

Comment: Also you could use a `vector<bool>`.  That should only take 256 bytes plus some book keeping.

Comment: @NathanOliver vector of bool will not serve me, the value (int) may contain real numbers not just 0 or 1

Comment: If `find(0)` returns `0`, what does it mean? Is '0' found or not found?

Comment: @Arun sorry did not get you

Comment: An unordered map adds quite a lot of overhead compared to a vector; unless the expected occupancy is very low, you'll probably find a std::array<int,256> to be both faster and smaller.

Comment: @rici I can not.. I will have a minimum of 3*800*600 of this container. and it will work on a kind of limited resource device. a full 256 value is not an option

Comment: My question is, if the caller queries for `0` and your function returns `0`, how would caller interpret the return value? Was `0` "found" or "not found"?

Comment: Use a `std::vector<std::pair<uint8_t,int>>` it occupies less space in memory than a `std::unordered_map`. Use of `std::find` would be as fast since you have a relatively small buffer to search into.

Comment: @Arun There is no such case. If it is exist, it must be at least 1.

Comment: I see, I was not clear of the constraint that the mapped value is at least 1. Since it is an `int` it could have been anything.

Comment: @NathanOliver Get it..? _find_ anything faster..? .. I'll show myself out.

Comment: The container can have at least these three different operations: (1) insert a key value pair, (2) erase a key value pair, and (3) query for a key. I have two  questions now: (A) What are the expected percentages of these three operations? (B) Does op#3 is expected many times in a row without intervening op#1 and op#2?

Comment: @Arun I edited. thanks for your time

Comment: Surely the best way to test for performance improvements here is to benchmark the few choices of data structures you have available to you and then find a compromise between memory usage and search time. `std::unordered_map` is likely to give you the best results in the latter case but if the former is an issue then using a `std::vector`/`std::array` of `std::pair`s could be a good compromise.

Comment: @humam: if the average occupancy is less than 10, then your data structure probably uses less space, but perhaps not as little as you think. My guess is that each entry will cost you between 32 and 40 bytes on average (or maybe more), including alloc overhead, plus the overhead of the hash table metadata, which is on the order of 64 bytes per map. So a map with 10 entries will occupy something like 400 bytes. The vector of 256 ints would need 1024 bytes. On the other hand, if your estimated occupancy turns out to be low, the storage cost for the map will explode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a trade-off between memory and speed.

Your `unordered_map` should have the less speed complexity.

Using `std::vector<std::pair<uint8_t, int>>` would be more compact (and more cache friendly).

`std::pair<std::vector<uint8_t>, std::vector<int>>` would be even more compact (no padding between `uint8_t` and `int`)

You can even do better by factorizing size/capacity, but it is no longer in `std::`.

With `vector`, you have then an other trade of: complexity for searching and add key:

- unsorted vector: constant add, Linear search
- sorted vector: linear add (due to insert value in middle of vector), logarithmic search.

Answer (score 0):

I might use a vector for space compactness.

It is tempting to keep it sorted for logarithmic search performance. But since the expected number of elements is less than 10, I might just leave it unsorted and use linear search.

So

```
vector<pair<uint8_t, int>> data;
```

---

If the number of expected elements is large, then having a sorted vector might help.

Boost offers a map-like interface with vector-like layout. See `boost flat_map` at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx